# Compatibility of Mid 2011 MacBook Air 13" Parts

Tags: macbook-pro

I am replacing the upper case of my MBA 2011 13", I found something on eBay but am unsure on the compatibility, my serial number is, C02GRGLVDJWT.

Link to the part: [13" Apple MacBook Air A1466 Palmrest Upper Top Case 069-8219-A](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/13-Apple-MacBook-Air-A1466-Palmrest-Upper-Top-Case-069-8219-A-/111885791557?hash=item1a0ce9b145:g:GbAAAOSwpRRWpl0q).  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
Serial No: C02GRGLVDJWT
Apple MacBook Air i5 1.7 13" (Mid-2011)
Part No: MC965LL/A
Model Identifier: MacBookAir4,2
Model No: A1369

Apple MacBook Air i7 2.0 13" (Mid-2012)
Part No: MD232LL/A
Model Identifier: MacBookAir5,2
Model No: A1466
```

Between these 2 machines, casing parts are **NOT** interchangeable

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, but it's probably not worth betting on it. Instead, buy one such as [this](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Apple-Macbook-Air-A1369-2011-13-Palmrest-Top-Case-Backlit-Keyboard-069-6952-A-/111889747592?hash=item1a0d260e88:g:YIwAAOSw5dNWq9Wd) that corresponds to your computer.